# Trying to change out a ceiling fan need help... 5 wires

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan, old-house

I'm in an old house. I removed and replaced 2 out of 3 with no problem. I get to the third and there are 5 wires: 2 black, 2 white/cream, and one bare copper wire. I think I have it hooked up right but the breaker flips when I turn power on. What am I doing wrong?[image][image][image]

Comment: How many switches are on the wall?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the switch and fan boxes?

Comment: There is one to this room (switch)!

Comment: My phone takes to good of pics and it's getting dark I'll try again tomorrow on pics

Comment: `I think I have it hooked up right` ... that is a very poor description of how you hooked it up

Comment: Sir I have called friends that would know and there saying I dont have my grounds right but I cant get any pics up I put the 2 white cream ones with white the 2 blacks with black then the copper with green

Comment: was the fan working correctly just before you replaced it? ..... i'm wondering if the problem could be at one of the other two fans.

Comment: Yes it was... so I need to back track? They were simple though just the 3 wires?

Comment: @Cwil -- if you can't get image uploading to work here, post them to [imgur](https://imgur.com) and link them here, and we can then work out the details from there.

Comment: Sometimes with old house the problem is that previous work was not right, making it diffcult to sort out.  For example, if someone uses 14/2 cable to go from ceiling box to a switch, they would probably connect black to black in box, then at switch connect black to one side, white to the other.  Then back in ceiling box, woudl connect white coming from switch to fan black.  Well, you can see the opportunity for confusion.  A nice install like that would put some black tape on that white wire to indicate it is hot (or, better yet, red tape, to indicate it is switched).

Comment: I added pics one of wall switch one how I had it hooked up (a bluetooth fan) and one without the fan on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note sure of how you connected them. If Load if attached to neutral its going to make a short circuit and Breaker flips.

Bare Copper wires is usually earthing. Usually black wire is Load and white wire is Neutral. If Black is joining to black(also white with white) then it represent a serial connection that may be used in some other place using the same switch.